# Use variable from one forEach Method in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, foreach

I am trying to use a value from inside one `getJSON`, `forEach` method in another. Is there any way for me to do that?

JavaScript

```
$.getJSON(json1, result => {
    result.forEach((elem, i, array) => {
       $('#x').text(elem.x);                            
       $('#y').text(elem.y);
});

$.getJSON(json2, result => {
    result.forEach((elem, i, array) => {
       $('#v').text(elem.v);                            
       $('#pv').text(elem.pv);
});
```

I want to use `elem.x` from `json1` inside `json2`. I need to be able to calculate `elem.x/elem.v`. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Write exactly what do you need

Comment: @DominikMatis, I need to divide `elem.x` from inside `json1` with `elem.v` inside of `json2`

Comment: Doesn't make sense changing text of same elements in each iteration of the loop. What exactly is it you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

By the comment you wrote, I'd prefer do it like this (think that both will have same length):

```
var first, second;
$.when(
    $.getJSON(json1, result => first = result),
    $.getJSON(json2, result => second = result)
).then(function() {
    if (first && second) {
        let results = first.map((item, index) => item.x / second[index].v);
        // do whatever you want
    }
});
```

Comment: Hope this is what you wanted, if so, please mark it as correct answer :)

Comment: Can also do `$.when($.getJSON(json1Url), $.getJSON(json2Url)).done((first, second)`

Comment: @DominikMatis I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` error at `).then...`

Comment: @charlietfl I have never used when... done. Can I get an example?

Comment: @noob are those arrays the same length? The syntax error is `map()` in answer is missing a closing `)` after `second[index].v`

Comment: @charlietfl, I did close that. But still getting the error. Yes, they are the same length

Comment: @noob Edit the other question with full details of what you did , link back to this answer and I will reopen it. Also give a bit more detail on output needed. Let me know when you are done

Comment: @charlietfl, I have added what I tried and explained the errors and my desired output