# Use variables from 2 different $.getJSON=>.forEach for calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, foreach

I am trying to use a value from inside one `getJSON`, `forEach` method in another. Is there any way for me to do that?

JSON:

json1:

```
[
{
    "date": "2019-07-05",
    "x": 1246567,
    "y": 598045
},
{
    "date": "2019-07-06",
    "x": 1021607,
    "y": 452854
}
]
```

json2:

```
[
{
    "date": "2019-07-05",
    "v": 3132769,
    "pv": 6643094
},
{
    "date": "2019-07-06",
    "v": 2643611,
    "pv": 6059584
}
]
```

JavaScript

```
$.getJSON(json1, result => {
    result.forEach((elem, i, array) => {
       $('#x').text(elem.x);                            
       $('#y').text(elem.y);
});

$.getJSON(json2, result => {
    result.forEach((elem, i, array) => {
       $('#v').text(elem.v);                            
       $('#pv').text(elem.pv);
});
```

I want to use `elem.x` from `json1` inside `json2`. I need to be able to calculate `elem.x/elem.v`. Is there any way to do that?

EDIT: When I do what is suggested in [Use variable from one forEach Method in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332585/use-variable-from-one-foreach-method-in-another).

```
var first, second;
$.when(
  $.getJSON(json1, result => first = result);
  $.getJSON(json2, result => second = result);
).then(function() {
  if (first && second) {
    let results = first.map((item, index) => item.x / second[index].v);
    // do whatever you want
  }
});
```

I am getting a `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list error at ).then...`. All the open...close brackets are right. Still getting errors.

Expected Output:

```
json1.x/json2.v
```

Comment: You asked the same question several days ago and got an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332585/use-variable-from-one-foreach-method-in-another What was wrong with that answer? Doesn't appear you ever asked for any clarification

Comment: I keep getting errors and I asked it again hoping for some more help on that. I added the json to make my data more clear

Comment: So don't start over...explain those errors and expand on it. This is not right to ignore the perfectly valid answer you already got for same problem

Comment: I get it. Thats what I will try and do

Comment: If you need to ask a new question...show what didn't work with that answer and link back to it also

Comment: @charlietfl edited this questions linking it to the other as well

Comment: Remove the `;` after both the `$.getJSON` and replace first one with a comma. They are parameters  for  `$.when(arg1, arg2)`

Comment: @charlietfl, then I am getting an error at second[index].v`)` and also `});`

Comment: try putting it in jshint.com ,,, will tell you what's wrong and give live updates as you fix each issue

Comment: @charlietfl  I am getting an undefined variable inside all the lines of the `when`. Also: here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rprak0605/cwr2vp9L/1/

Comment: Ohhhh I thought you were making ajax requests with `$.getJSON` and `json1` is a url. If you have data already in page then it is all wrong. If you already have the data then `first` and `second` are `json1` and `json2` and you don't use `$.when or $.getJSON

Comment: Is the data available in variables as in the fiddle? If so all you need is the `map()` part

Comment: json1 is a url. I just wanted to give the example of how tee data should look

Comment: @charlietfl, sorry for the confusion

Comment: ok....just wanted to make sure....then just need to resolve syntax errors

Comment: ok... i'll try and figure them out. thank you

Comment: @charlietfl, How can I use the `results` I get back in the `then` outside the function?

Comment: `;` is used to seperate statements, `,` is used to seperate arguments