# Use variable from inside $when...then() outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, highcharts

On a follow up from [Use variable from one forEach Method in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332585/use-variable-from-one-foreach-method-in-another). How can I use the value I get in the `then()` outside the function?

```
var first, second;
$.when(
  $.getJSON(json1, result => first = result);
  $.getJSON(json2, result => second = result);
).then(function() {
  if (first && second) {
    let results = first.map((item, index) => item.x / second[index].v);

  }
});
```

I want to use `results` outside of this function in another function.

I want to use these `results` values inside highcharts.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hi @noob, Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9t3zeymv/. After small changes your code seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize Highchart.js in the callback function.

```js
var first, second;
$.when(
  $.getJSON(json1, result => first = result);
  $.getJSON(json2, result => second = result);
).then(function() {
  if (first && second) {
    let results = first.map((item, index) => item.x / second[index].v);

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
      ...
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I am getting an `undefined` when I put in console log

Comment: @noob I understood what you want. You have to do something in the callback function or with Promise chaining.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry like my screen name, I am really a noob

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rprak0605/kc9g5vrh/ , the json is an url in my original code. But i created a fiddle